# INSERT in SELECT?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to loop over a set and insert a row for each, is this in SQLite?

Here's what I have, but I want to insert 1 item per skill_point_type. Right now its just grabbing one row from skill_point_type and inserting a single item:

```
INSERT INTO skill_points (skill_point_type_name, player_name, skill_points)
SELECT
    (SELECT name FROM skill_point_type),
    'hat', 
    0
```

Comment: are player_name and skill_points constant for all rows?

Comment: yes player_name and skill_points are constant. I'm saying "this player has 0 points in every skill".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO skill_points (skill_point_type_name, player_name, skill_points)
SELECT name, 'hat', 0 FROM skill_point_type
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'll accept your answer in 11 minutes apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO skill_points (skill_point_type_name, player_name, skill_points)
    SELECT name, 'hat',  0
    FROM skill_point_type;
```